# Simple equation solving in C

Tags: c, equation

I found that the `void main` isn't correct but even when I change it to `int` or erase it,

I'm not getting what I'm supposed to which is the value for X given the values for A and B for the equation ax+b=0 and all I get are zeroes.

How can i fix this ?

```
void main()
{
    float a,b,x=0;
    printf("\n Write the values for A and B");
    scanf("&%F&%F",&a,&b);
    if(a==0)printf("\n Not a valid operation");
    else{x=-b/a;
        printf("\n Answer is x=%f",x);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(a==0)` is not the correct way to check for error. If the scanf failed then `a` will be indeterminate, since you never initialized it. Also, it doesn't check if `b` was read successfully. To fix this either set `a=0` beforehand, or check the return value of `scanf`. It should be `2` if `2` items were read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the format specifiers to read `a` and `b` seem strange. Not sure whether you meant to have those `&` in there. Checkout the details of the valid format specifiers at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf.

Try:

```
scanf("%f%f",&a,&b);
```

`&` is not a format specifier. When you use

```
scanf("&%F&%F",&a,&b);
```

`scanf` expects the characters `&` in the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
scanf("%f%f",&a,&b);
```

instead of

```
  scanf("&%F&%F",&a,&b);
```